# React navigation - followed the docs but get an error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm very new to learning react and was simply following this example:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html

```
import { StackNavigator, } from 'react-navigation';
const App = StackNavigator(
 { Home: { screen: HomeScreen }, Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen }, });


class HomeScreen extends React.Component { 
   static navigationOptions = { title: 'Welcome', }; 
    render() { 
         const { navigate } = this.props.navigation; 
        return ( <Button title="Go to Jane's profile" onPress={() => navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' }) } /> ); } 
}
```

But when I run this I get an error that says

> "ProfileScreen is not defined"

I can't see what to do here since this wasn't on the documents page I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing a React component called ProfileScreen.  You have a HomeScreen:

```
    class HomeScreen extends React.Component { 
       static navigationOptions = { title: 'Welcome', }; 
        render() { 
            const { navigate } = this.props.navigation; 
            return ( 
                <Button 
                    title="Go to Jane's profile" 
                    onPress={() => navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' }) } 
                /> 
            ); 
        } 
     }
```

Now just define some kind of ProfileScreen:

```
const ProfileScreen = () => (
    <View>
        <Text>ProfileScreen</Text>
    </View>
);
```

Comment: Thanks..I just added that..now the error is "Route 'Home' should declare a screen".  This seems strange since that appears what is happening in the const App line above.

Comment: You just need to put the app component after the other two.

Comment: Thank you. Will check this out in morning.

Comment: Thanks again....this worked and it helped me better understand what is going on with react.